# How can I prevent bottom scroll bar from appearing?

Tags: javascript, css, skrollr

On this [dev URL](http://workwave.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/) I use skrollr to make desk items *slide away*.  the action takes place between scroll position 0 and 300. Anywhere in between there, the bottom scroll bar appears bc items are moving off the right side of the page.  At 300, all items that moved off to the right of the page get "display: none" assigned, so they disappear and the scroll bar goes away.

Is there anyway to prevent the scroll bar from EVER appearing?

Comment: Please include a sample of the code within your question for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is on the x-axis, you can use `overflow:hidden`:

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden !important;
  }
```

This will ensure no scrolling on the body's x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

kurt you are correct but this will only hide the overflow at the bottom of your page the you have content here:

```
<section class="t3-copyright">
        <div class="container">
```

This div spans more than the width of the page set the container div max-width:100%; and the scroll bar will go away.